# [OAuth][Keycloak] invalid_grant session not active when trying to use refresh_token

Tags: oauth-2.0, keycloak, openid-connect, refresh-token

I'm trying to refresh the oauth2 token using ClientOAuth2.Token.refresh() but keep getting the error sometimes:
`{"error":"invalid_grant","error_description":"Session not active"}`

This is the request which I captured by Fiddler

```
POST [URL]= HTTP/1.1
Host: [URL]
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 2250
Accept: application/json, application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Origin: http://localhost:8080
Authorization: Basic YXNpbW92LWRldi1laGlzLXdlYjo=
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/77.0.3865.90 Safari/537.36
Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Sec-Fetch-Site: cross-site
Referer: http://localhost:8080/
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en,vi;q=0.9,de;q=0.8,vi-VN;q=0.7,en-US;q=0.6,en-AU;q=0.5

refresh_token=[token]&grant_type=refresh_token
```

Maybe somethings wrong with my setting on KeyCloak account. Are there any suggestions?

Answer (score 9):

You need to add the scope [offline_access](https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html#OfflineAccess) when retrieving the original token, otherwise you won't be able to refresh it when the related user session is not active (this is specific to OIDC, not oauth2).

Answer (score 1):

Could be that your refresh token grant message is incomplete - missing a client ID or offline access scope - see the [Refresh Token Grant](https://authguidance.com/2020/05/24/spa-and-api-final-http-messages/) section of my article on OAuth messages.

Answer (score 0):

You can edited your **cache-ispn.xml** in **conf** folder to limit offline session caches to size as you required like below

```
<distributed-cache name="offlineSessions" owners="2">
    <memory max-count="2"/>
    <expiration lifespan="-1"/>
</distributed-cache>
<distributed-cache name="offlineClientSessions" owners="2">
     <memory max-count="2"/>
     <expiration lifespan="-1"/>
</distributed-cache>
```

Reference from [here](https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/issues/9959)

Answer (score -5):

It is because you are logged out from you client application. That's why it giving you the error.